# Get shared buckets from Google Cloud Storage using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage

I want to download some reports from Google Cloud Storage and I'm trying the [Gcloud gem](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-ruby/). I managed to successfully connect and now I am able to list my buckets, create one, etc.

But I can't find a way to programically get files from buckets, which are shared with me. I got and address like `gs://pubsite...` and I need to connect to that bucket, to download some files. How can I achieve that?
Do I need to have billing enabled?

Answer (score 2):

In order to list all the object in a bucket you can use [Google Cloud Storage Object list API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list).

You need to provide the Bucket ID and should have the access to the bucket to read the objects. You can try the API before implementing it in your code.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need billing enabled to download objects from a GCS bucket. Operations on GCS buckets are billed to the project that owns the bucket. You only need to enable billing in order to create a new bucket.

Downloading a single file using the Gcloud gem looks like this:

```
require "gcloud"

gcloud = Gcloud.new
storage = gcloud.storage
bucket = storage.bucket "pubsite"
file = bucket.file "somefile.png"
file.download "/tmp/somefile.png"
```

There are some examples at http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-ruby/docs/v0.2.0/Gcloud/Storage.html

Comment: So basically this bucket should be available when I run `storage.buckets` ? Because I have nil response when I do that.

Comment: storage.buckets returns a list of buckets that are owned by your project. It will not list buckets owned by other projects.